# FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage and FormAuthenticationTicket webforms

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm still new to webforms and I'm a bit confused. I was doing Authentication with

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        bool rememberUsername = false;

        SqlDbAccess db = new SqlDbAccess();
        int result = db.ValidateLogin(username, password);

        switch (result)
        {
            case -1:
                lblValidationError.Text = "Utilizador / Password incorrecto";
                break;
            case -2:
                lblValidationError.Text = "Conta desactivada";
                break;
            default:
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text, false);               
                break;
        }
}
```

and because I need to get roles I have this

```
       string roles = db.GetRoles(result);

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
        (
            1, 
            username, 
            DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), 
            rememberUsername, 
            roles, 
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        );

        string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        if (returnUrl == null)
            returnUrl = "~/Default.aspx";

        Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Question is... Do I have to use both FormsAuthentication methods or can I just use Ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` states:

> Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default URL.

Notice the word "authenticated"... In your first snippet, you are checking credentials and doing a redirect. You are ***not*** setting the forms auth cookie as you are doing in your second snippet. I actually think the combined code should look something like this:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = txtUsername.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    bool rememberUsername = false;

    SqlDbAccess db = new SqlDbAccess();
    int result = db.ValidateLogin(username, password);

    switch (result)
    {
        case -1:
            lblValidationError.Text = "Utilizador / Password incorrecto";
            break;
        case -2:
            lblValidationError.Text = "Conta desactivada";
            break;
        default:
            // not certain what should be passed in here???
            string roles = db.GetRoles(username);

            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
            (
                1, 
                username, 
                DateTime.Now, 
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), 
                rememberUsername, 
                roles, 
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            );

            string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, rememberUsername);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, so many methods still makes me a bit confused in webforms, I gave up on memberships because I don't need all those extra tables and columns,